# Issue on Navigation manager listener and Position manager listener in Android [here-api]

Tags: here-api, heremaps-android-sdk

Navigation and simulation is working fine for the first day and then when same actions are performed on next day, navigation manager listeners and position listeners are not working. But when I clear the app storage data, they start to work again only for that day and no errors are shown in the implementation. I have implemented the functionality using the reference projects in GitHub Turn-by-turn navigation project.

https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Storage should not block functionality of HERE SDK.

Or you can try to see if there was any callback of PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener or NavigationManager.PositionListener triggered?